# How to convert .htaccess to web.config

Tags: .htaccess, web-config, codeigniter-3

I have this .htaccess file which works great with Apache, but I am now forced to use IIS, hence need to convert from .htaccess to web.config.  How do I make it a web.config file?  I tried the online converters, but it didn't work.  Also does the web.config file go in the root directory like the .htaccess file did?  I am using Codeigniter 3.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Here is what the converter gave me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="rule 1l" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$"  />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/./index.php/{R:1}"  />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The links etc work correctly, but there is no formatting.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out. The `web.config` file posted above is fine. The issue was changing the link in the style sheets from `HTTP` to `HTTPS`. Easy fix!